# SSL Issues with Mixed Content and Firefox

Tags: ssl, configuration

my question is about SSL with Drupal. I've uploaded my certs to my server and got everything installed and working correctly. I've set the base_url to be my https://site domain and also put the following at the top of my htaccess file:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Everything seems good on all my site pages on IE and Chrome. But Firefox keeps giving me a mixed content warning:

Firefox is blocking content on this page.
Some unencyrypted elements on this page have been blocked.

Why would it still be saying this if I have a properly working SSL cert (which I do) and it covers my entire site? Is there a way to get rid of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `$base_url`, Drupal always uses it in email absolute links and whenever it has to build an absolute URL.

I have many sites running full-HTTPS, with only the $base_url set to the https URL.

We can't debug your site for you, but check the page source to see if any Javascript files are being served via HTTP. 
Google Analytics, Google fonts, Google translate widgets, banners, ad serving scripts, CDN-served jQuery, etc.

Header tracking and other debug features won't probably work in your browser because when the page URL is in HTTPS, browsers do not load HTTP assets. You can still check the page source to see the HTTP references.

Comment: thank you for the answer. That gives me something to work with. I appreciate it.